# using chromedriver for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the chromeDriver to work with selenium. But I am unable to get it working even with the path set.

I am downloading the chrome-driver and the selenium-server as follows, using a gradle task

```
webtestsCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.32.0'
webtestsCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.35.0'
```

these 2 are the latest version available on the maven central repository

I am setting the

```
webdriver.chrome.driver to 

/home/bhavya/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server/2.35.0/jar/e3f840bdd41ad805fac202695c93f7861fdf4552/selenium-server-2.35.0.jar
```

The chrome driver and the selenium server are present in the classPath a snippet of the classPath is :

```
 /home/bhavya/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.35.0/jar/e1e66d33eb849c1e721b4937da1eda96789a59f3/selenium-chrome-driver-2.35.0.jar:/home/bhavya/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server/2.35.0/jar/e3f840bdd41ad805fac202695c93f7861fdf4552/selenium-server-2.35.0.jar
```

I am trying to get the chromeDriver up and running using this code :

```
        ChromeDriverService cds =
                 ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
        try {
            cds.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         driver = new ChromeDriver(cds); 
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When I run my test case I see the following error :

invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error
Gradle Worker 1 finished executing tests.

heimdall.ui.admin.UserEditControllerWebTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
    Caused by:
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
    Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
    System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.5.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
        at heimdall.ui.webtest.DriverUtil.getDriver(DriverUtil.java:75)
        at heimdall.ui.webtest.DriverUtil.createDriver(DriverUtil.java:55)
        at heimdall.ui.admin.UserEditControllerWebTest.<clinit>(UserEditControllerWebTest.java:32)

        Caused by:
        org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:7826/status] to be available after 20003 ms
            at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
            ... 3 more

            Caused by:
            com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
                at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
                ... 4 more

                Caused by:
                java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
                    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
                    ... 5 more
 Process 'Gradle Worker 1' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
```

Edit 2 :

more information regrading the chrome browser --

```
bhavya@bhavya-ums:~/git/heimdall_06_11$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/google-chrome
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Nov 19 12:05 /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
bhavya@bhavya-ums:~/git/heimdall_06_11$ which chrome 
< does not return anything> I think by default on ubuntu it makes use of the chromium browser
```

Comment: AFAIK, the server download doesn't include the ChromeDriver, it is seperate to everything else: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/

Comment: I have checked with both the chrome driver as well as the server added to webdriver.chrome.driver. it does not work with either, it in the above case, the chrome-driver is present in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

put the webdriver binary into /usr/bin/

does your chrome instance opens ?

Comment: tried your suggestion put the selenium-server-2.35.0.jar in the usr/bin location, I do not see any modification in the behaviour. My chrome instance does not open. I am ubuntu 12.04

Comment: chrome driver should be in /usr/bin, not selenium !

Comment: @RaduToader just completed testing-- with your suggestion this does not seem to be helping either.